# How to select an Amazon EC2 kernel?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

When launching an instance, I'm presented with this most cryptic list:

[image]

There seems to be absolutely zero documentation on Amazon as to which kernel does what. They explain fairly well what these kernels are *for*, but without knowing what those numbers mean, kernels appear to be utterly useless.

Where can I find out what a given kernel means, or what the latest kernel is for a given OS?

Comment: Unless you have a specific kernel-based requirement (perhaps a bugfix or feature) there's no need to deviate from the default kernel.

Comment: If you don't know what it is, you don't need to change it from Default.

Comment: @Tom If only the AWS documentation said that then I wouldn't have asked this question... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernels are usually very tightly coupled with the OS they're supposed to run along. Usually, we rather use a AMI (Amazon Machine Image) which includes both the Kernel (AKI) and the associated AMI data to ensure the whole VM will boot without error.

To identify a given AMI, you should use some tools:

- Firefox ElasticFox plugin that helps you exploring the images ( http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/609?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1 )
- If you know what kind of distro you want, you can for example have a look at Alestic webpage (for ubuntu): http://alestic.com/index.html . I'm pretty confident there exists other AMI repositories.
- Command Line tools can also help you searching and listing the available AMI.

Good Luck with EC2 :-)